# XSLT 3.0 evaluate into variable

Tags: xml, variables, evaluation, xslt-3.0

For the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
   <pi:company>
      <pi:employee>
         <pi:name>John Andrews</pi:name>
         <pi:age>23</pi:age>
         <pi:salary>4000</pi:salary>
         <pi:division>Accounting</pi:division>
      </pi:employee>
   </pi:company>
</pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
```

I use this XSL to store the value in a variable using `xsl:evaluate` and then output the value from name node that is stored in in `$names` ("John Andrews"):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 

xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
        <xsl:output method="text"/>
            <xsl:template match="pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees/pi:company">
                <xsl:variable name="test">
                <xsl:text>pi:employee/pi:name</xsl:text>
            </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="names" as="element(name)*">
                <xsl:evaluate xpath="$test" context-item="."/>
            </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$names"/>
            </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you explain what your problem is please?  What exactly have you tried, and what (if anything) is not going as you'd hoped, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the namespace declaration you have the type annotation of the variable needs to be

```
    <xsl:variable name="names" as="element(pi:name)*">
        <xsl:evaluate xpath="$test" context-item="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working for me, what xslt processor do you use?

Comment: I tried with Saxon 9.8.0.5 EE inside oXygen 19.1. What exactly happens when it "does not seem to be working", do you get an error, which result do you want, which one do you get?

Comment: I use Saxon 9.6.0.7 EE so i think it is causing the problem.

Comment: I am afraid Saxon 9.6 is rather old when it comes to the XSLT 3 spec of this year, its documentation https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/conformance/xslt30.html states that it implements the XSLT 3 last call working draft from 2 October 2014 so the problem you have might be caused by differences between the final spec and that draft or by unresolved problems in that Saxon release.